# Problems with PHP DB Connection

Tags: php, mysql, sql, shopware6

So i have an SQL query, that looks like this and when executing I get no value for my result and no change in my database.
Whats the problem here?

```
$result = $db->query("UPDATE product SET price=$price WHERE id=0x$data[0]");
print_r($result);
```

Comment: can you please print `$price` and `0x$data[0]` and share here? and print `$db` as well

Comment: $result = $db->query("UPDATE product SET price='$price' WHERE id=0x$data[0]");
Solved the problem using ''

Comment: Please consider using the repositories of shopware. This way all the events will be triggered for other extensions.